# Fix folder permissions - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, permissions, apache2, directory

Friends,

I accidentally set the permissions to /var/www folder as chmod -R 775 /var/www instead of chmod -R 755 /var/www for a new user (not ROOT - but a new super user) I created on my VPS server.

Is there a way to reset the permissions to its original settings?

I am having multiple domains hosted on my VPS and I need to give permissions to website folders individually.

Kindly suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Login as root , then set the permissions back?

Comment: Welcome, what's wrong with setting the permissions again with 755?

Comment: "for a new user", what do you mean by that? That the user is the owner?

Comment: [This could help you](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver).

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to reset the Apache directories to what they typically are after installation, you can do this:

1. Ensure the `/var/www` directories and files have the correct read/write permissions:
   `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`
2. Ensure the `/var/www` directories and files belong to the correct owner and group:
   `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

That is all.

Comment: This is not all, this will make every file executable, I suggest you do not do this.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

1. If you have another server with /var/www directory listed there, list out the permissions and ownerships on the files on the "good" system and then use those values to fix the "incorrect" settings on your other server.
2. Make a backup of any custom changes in the /var/www directory, then perform a re-install on the apache package. (apt-get reinstall {pkg-name})

Backups are important here because you mentioned that you have multiple domains on your VPS. I assume that means there may be configuration files and custom data in /var/www folders you don't want to lose during any reinstall attempt.

Personally, I'd go with Option 1. Even if I had to install another Ubuntu server with Apache to be able to see the default ownerships and permissions to use as a reference.